# How to optimize this mariogpt script

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import torch
from mario_gpt import MarioLM

mario_lm = MarioLM()

def my_function():
    mario_lm.sample(
        prompts=["some pipes, some enemies, some blocks, low elevation"],
        num_steps=1400,
    ).play()
    my_function()
my_function()
```

But after that executing it, it makes levels generate too laggy, with 10 steps per second and i dont know how to fix it.

I tried to change the temperature and it doesnt seem to work, and i tried to train it and change the prompts but their dont work.

Comment: Can you give more technical detail than "doesn't work"?

Comment: It works slowly, thats the technical detail.